# Parent Keys Not Found?

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

One of the classic questions...

But I really can't find where the issue is in the parent table. I am currently working on a mini-version of the IMDB database. Our teacher tasked us with taking the original database we were given and make it into a smaller, and smarter version. It should follow this diagram:

[image: Database Diagram]

I have so far successfully made the COMPANY_NAME, MOVIE_COMPANY, MOVIE, GENRE and PLOT tables and is currently making KEYWORD. The table itself now exists, but I cannot place the Foreign constraint which indicates that the MOVIE_ID present in keyword is from the parent table MOVIE. I keep getting the following error:

```
ALTER TABLE KEYWORD
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_MOVIE_ID_KEYWORD
    FOREIGN KEY (MOVIE_ID)
    REFERENCES MOVIE (ID)
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-02298: cannot validate (DB_031.FK_MOVIE_ID_KEYWORD) - parent keys not found
02298. 00000 - "cannot validate (%s.%s) - parent keys not found"
*Cause:    an alter table validating constraint failed because the table has
           child records.
*Action:   Obvious <-- especially this part is annoying
```

I have looked around at similar questions and then checked my statement a few times, but I have so far been unable to see why this fails. The GENRE and PLOT tables are both empty in terms of data, as they are made for future expansion of the database. But KEYWORD already have a collection of KEYWORD, MOVIE_ID pairs.

EDIT: Request Schemas

[image: Movie Schema]

[image: Keyword Schema]

Comment: does table `MOVIE` has `ID` col???

Comment: in the image the `ID` column is also named `movie_id` (as in your referencing tables) so you would have to use `REFERENCES MOVIE (MOVIE_ID)`

Comment: The `MOVIE_ID` on the ER-diagram is to show that it is the `ID` belonging to a movie so that you don't get it mixed up with a different `ID` from another table. In the table itself it is still called `ID`.

Comment: @Vipar: You have records present in `keyword` table??

Comment: @Gone : 17secs early....+1 to your comment!! :)

Comment: anyway, +1 to the question. Supplied/edited with nice schema images in an instant after we asked for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing to wrong `col` for parent reference....it should be `MOVIE_ID` rather than `ID` ( *which u have done* )

try it this way :

```
ALTER TABLE KEYWORD
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_MOVIE_ID_KEYWORD
    FOREIGN KEY (MOVIE_ID)
    REFERENCES MOVIE (MOVIE_ID) /* <- notice this */
```

**EDIT**

Only possible reason i can think of is that you table contains non-matching data....that's why you are having an error due to mismatch!!

To simplyfy....your `MOVIE_ID` contains value which do not exist in the `ID` column of the other table....so because of mismatch at the time of setting up constraint,its popping the error!!

**Solution :** Validate the data in your tables ( *updating / deleting non-matching columns in either tables* ) in relation to the `id`'s you need to set up...then apply the constraint and it should work!!

Comment: This, and I would like to add ( not to the answer, more for the professor ), naming a column `company_name` ( table_columnname )  in a `company` table is quite bad style... same for movie.movie_id, etc.

Comment: @NoobEditor The `MOVIE_ID` on the ER-diagram is to show that it is the `ID` belonging to a movie so that you don't get it mixed up with a different `ID` from another table. In the table itself it is still called `ID`.

Comment: @Vipar : yeah i read that...can you show your table schema for both the tables???

Comment: @Najzero As with the `MOVIE_ID` thing, the name of the company is still called `NAME` in the table, but labelled as `COMPANY_NAME` to clear confusion in the diagram.

Comment: @Vipar : i notice that in order *to clear confusion* , you have only added more confusion....can u present actual data, not worrying about us to get confused!!! :)

Comment: I put the schemas in the main post.

Comment: Oh well... I just saw `*Cause:    an alter table validating constraint failed because the table has
           child records.` - you have to empty your (child)table before adding a CONSTRAINT like that. ( tip -> CREATE DUMMY_TABLE AS SELECT * FROM ... , and then insert them after adding the constraint )

Comment: @Najzero : ditto thoughts!!

Comment: I checked that entries from `MOVIE` exists in `KEYWORD` by doing a simple `SELECT * FROM MOVIE WHERE ID IN (SELECT MOVIE_ID FROM KEYWORD);` But it's not true that the table needs to be empty. Because I could add primary and foreign keys on other tables which also has data. So there must be some sort of mismatch but I simply cannot see what it is.

Comment: @vipar : do this query, `select m.id, mi.movie_id from table1 m left outer join table2 mi on m.id=mi.movie_id` and check the `NULL` values...that should give u some clue for debugging!!! ( *replace table1 and table2 with table names* )

Comment: @Vipar : query u currently did wont give u *extra* values in the table....and these *different* values are screwing up your query!! :)

Comment: So, do you suggest I remove all null values?

Comment: null values as `foreign key` doesnt makes sense esp when they are matched against a primary key...dont u think??? :)

Comment: just make sure that the 2 columns `id` and `movie_id` have got no different set of values, `ID` can be extra...but `MOVIE_ID` **has to be** present in `ID` columns, so that matching may occur!!

Comment: @NoobEditor I tried this `DELETE FROM KEYWORD WHERE MOVIE_ID IS NULL;` but it says it removed 0 rows.

Comment: @NoobEditor Okay, I made it work but I have no way of checking that what I got left is actually the right amount of keywords :'). I ran this: `DELETE FROM KEYWORD WHERE MOVIE_ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM MOVIE);` which removed 37,000 rows so I must have made quite a bad query beforehand. Thanks though, I will accept the answer.